# PHP: How to match certain constraints and not another with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that would match `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`, but only if it doesn't match `admin`.

The idea is to block `admin` and let everything else match the regex above.

Any ideas?

Comment: `if ($var != 'admin' && // regex`

Comment: Can't use php here, we are talking about zf2 configuration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to rule out "admin":

```
^(?!admin$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

The idea is that you needs something like `(?!^admin$)` at the beginning to assert that the input does not match "admin".

Comment: It is a controller constraint in zf2 route configuration, so I had to modify it a bit, but it actually worked: `(?!admin)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` Thanks!

Comment: @Tony: Removing the anchors makes the input "admin" result in the match "dmin" -- you should be aware of that.

Comment: Wouldn't that regex invalid names like `adming`?

Comment: @jackflash: Yes, good catch. I added another `$` after `admin` to address this.